# sending a daily digest of content (add, edit, delete) actions by email

Tags: 8, entities, emails

I am trying to send a daily digest of all the content entities that have been added, edited or deleted. 
I am working on Drupal 8 so most of the good modules that achieve that are unstable and incomplete, what can i do? can someone point me to the right direction ?

a really good example would be in Drupal interface, when opening `Reports->Recent log messages` then filter them by `content`. Can i somehow send them by email ? and filtering them by date, so I only sent the recent ones..

Comment: Configure a cron on your server to call `cd /var/ww/mydrupal && drush cron` once a day. In a custom module use `hook_cron` to fetch your content and trigger a mail.

Comment: This sounds like it could do the job of sending https://www.drupal.org/project/message_digest and you just need to gather the content, have you tried it ?

Comment: Funny story: this was the first thing I ever did with Drupal 4.6, and I made a janky perl script to basically do what leymannx suggested. I would probably use or write a module similar to what GiorgosK suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.
when you say "fetch your content" or "gather the content", that's a mystery, how to do it? should i fetch all nodes and then check the "created" and "changed" fields and compare, but then, how will i know if a node is deleted?, and what if i have A LOT of nodes .. is there a way to access the logs in "Reports->Recent log messages" through a custom module ?. Thanks for suggesting message_digest, maybe this a better replacement for the hook_corn.I was dodging the custom module route, but guess there is no running from that :( @mradcliffe